# Can I define my own runtime paramet like GOOS or GOARCH in golang?

Tags: go

For some reason I want to use a paramet which define when building. Such as `GOLIB=A go build` or `GOLIB=B go build`, and  use it like:

```
if runtime.GOLIB == "A"{
    //dosomething
}
if runtime.GOLIB == "B"{
    //dosomething
}
```

Is there anyway to did it?

Modify:

The really problem is that I have a new OS (suppoose called A ) which is similar with linux but has some different I/O operation. So I want to define my own class like `fd_A.go`,`syscall_A.go`(just like `fd_unix.go/fd_windows.go` and `syscall.unix.go/syscall.windows.go`),which implement the method like `Bind,Accept,Recvform,Connect`etc.

And the upper method such as`UDP,TCP,HTTP` will use the method I define when build project use `go build -tags A`, but using origin method without `-tags A`.

Comment: Whats wrong with just using normal environment variables?

Comment: Sorry,I modify the question to description my real question.In fact my code should run on a private platform

Comment: Adding the OS A to the list of supported OS's in the cimpiler would be the actual solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry,Is there any article guide me adding the OS A to the list of supported OS's in the cimpiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to did it?

No, at least not how you think this stuff works. (You cannot modify package runtime.)

You have two options:

- Build Tags and files defining appropriate values based on the build tag used.
- Inject a value during linkage with `-ldflags "-X 'your/package/path.VariableName=YourValueHere'`

This sound like an XY problem.

Comment: You are right ,I modify the question to description my real question. I think the build tags is a good solution

Comment: Maybe worth noting that build tags are also how OP's example works. It doesn't just pass the environment variables straight through to `runtime`. The compiler applies them to build constraints, and build constrains are used to determine the values of those constants at compile time.